# Typedef parameters and functions

Tags: c, function, typedef

I have the following piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

typedef char km_ph;
typedef double nnew;

int printme(km_ph b){
        printf ("%c  %d\n", b,b);
        return 0;
    }

int main() {

    km_ph a = 'o';
    nnew b = 100.09;
    printme(9);
    printme(a);
    printme(b); 
    return 0;
}
```

I expected `printme(b)` and `printme(9)` to throw some type of warning or error since the type of `b` is not the type of parameter that can be passed to `printme`. `printme` expects `km_ph` type, or at least `char` type. I get the following output:

> ```
>                     9
>  0        111
>  d        100
> ```

why does this happen?

Comment: Enable all recommended warnings! C does not prevent you from shooting your foot, but modern compilers can be augmented against such flaws.

Comment: @Olaf, didn't help. Or did I miss some? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a4f676d7809551e

Comment: What was unclear about "**all** recommended warnings"? How about reading the documentation of your compiler? (you did not state which one you use!)

Comment: @Olaf, how about actually entering the link where I specified `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` as options that work for both gcc and clang (at least according to their documentation, which I have read).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the compiler, running FlexLint on it gives this (see significant prototype coercion)

```
FlexeLint for C/C++ (Unix) Vers. 9.00L, Copyright Gimpel Software 1985-2014 
--- Module: diy.c (C)
     1  #include <stdio.h> 
     2  
     3  typedef char km_ph;
     4  typedef double nnew;
     5  
     6  int printme(km_ph b){
     7          printf ("%c  %d\n", b,b);
     8          return 0;
     9      }
    10  
    11  int main() {
    12  
    13      km_ph a = 'o';
    14      nnew b = 100.09;
                      _
    15      printme(9);
diy.c  15  Warning 534:  Ignoring return value of function 'printme(char)' (compare with line 6)
                      _
    16      printme(a);
diy.c  16  Warning 534:  Ignoring return value of function 'printme(char)' (compare with line 6)
                     _
    17      printme(b); 
diy.c  17  Warning 524:  Loss of precision (arg. no. 1) (double to char)
diy.c  17  Info 747:  Significant prototype coercion (arg. no. 1) double to char
diy.c  17  Warning 534:  Ignoring return value of function 'printme(char)' (compare with line 6)
    18      return 0;
    19  }
    20
```

[see](http://gimpel-online.com//cgi-bin/genPage.py?srcFile=diy.c&cgiScript=analyseCode.py&title=Do-It-Yourself%20Example%20%28C%29&intro=This%20example%20allows%20you%20to%20specify%20your%20own%20C%20code.&compilerOption=online32.lnt&includeOption=%7B%7BquotedIncludeOption%7D%7D)

That is why it is always good to have some kind of static code analyzer in your projects.

Answer (score 1):

`typedef` has nothing to do with this. Here is a simpler example:

```
void f(char ch) { }

int main() { f(100.09); }
```

It seems from your text as if you expect this should be an error. But it is not. Floating point types may be implicitly converted to integer types (`char` is an integer type), and the result is the floating point value is truncated towards zero. So `ch` becomes `100` in this example and that is what you saw in your program.

As mentioned in other comments/answers, some compilers have switches that will produce warning messages for these conversions.

Comment: but they are not of the same type!

Comment: Also, how do you explain `printme(9)` ? 9, of 4 bytes, should be truncated to 1 byte but that does not happen.

Comment: @Fabulous C has implicit conversion between different types

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "4 bytes, should be truncated to 1 byte"  . Nothing like that happens nor should it.  `printme(9)` results in `printf("%c  %d\n", 9, 9);` which prints the tab character followed by the character `9`.

Comment: @Fabulous `char` is an integer type; `9` is an integer. What you are seeing is the character whose code is `9`, which is a `TAB` (hence why the `9` of the first line of your output is shifted to the right).

Comment: @Fabulous converting `9` to `char` gives the `char` with value 9. Integer and floating conversions in C are defined in terms of values,   not memory representations.  The compiler will issue whatever instruction is necessary so that passing `9` causes the function to receive `9`.